# Downgrade Linux Minor Version

Tags: linux, upgrade, yum, downgrade, oracle-linux

I ran `yum update-minimal` at Oracle Linux 7.4 and the version has been upgraded to 7.5 unfortunately. How can I downgrade the version to 7.4? And why "update-minimal" changed the minor version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MAN on yum-security which implements update-minimal](https://linux.die.net/man/8/yum-security):

> The update-minimal command can only directly affect things atm., so if you update pkgA minimally but that requires an update to pkgB then pkgB will be updated to the newest version by the depsolver. Also the above will happen even if you've also minimally updated pkgB, if either the direct (minimal) update for pkgB happens after or if the minimal update for pkgB doesn't satisfy the requirements of pkgA.

One of the updates likely required packages that bumped you to 7.5. For a downgrade you likely would have to have a list of every package that was upgrade and uninstall/restore the previous versions of those packages. Restoring a backup is likely easier.